# Explanation of a awk command step by step

Tags: awk

Can you explain me what doing this command step by step?

`awk ' {file[$0]++} END { for (j in file) {print j,file[j]} } '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk ' {                # call awk

        # file -> is array
        # $0 -> current row/line/record
        # here $0 is used array index/key
        # ++ is post increment meaning
        # if line was found before it will increment by 1 
        # so file[$0]++ holds count of occurrence of line
        # suppose you got 4 lines, in that 3 are duplicates, then
        # for such index file[<such_line>] will be 3 
        file[$0]++

      }
       # end block as name suggests executes at the end

  END {
         # loop through array file
         # j as index 
         for (j in file) {

             # print array key, and array value
             print j,file[j]
         } 
      } 
   ' file
```

Example :

```
$ cat infile
lineA
lineB
lineA
lineB
lineA
lineC

$ awk ' {file[$0]++} END { for (j in file)print j,"repeated",file[j],"times in file :",FILENAME }' infile
lineA repeated 3 times in file : infile
lineB repeated 2 times in file : infile
lineC repeated 1 times in file : infile
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me so much you too!

Answer (score 1):

Following may help you in same.

```
awk ' {
file[$0]++   ##creating an array named file and with respect to current line as index, incrementing its count each time with one if same entry comes in array file.
} 
END {        ##Starts END section of awk code here.
for (j in file) {  ##starting for loop which will traverse through array file.
print j,file[j]    ##Printing value of j(which will be index of array named file(or other words current line value)) and printing the value of array file with index of j.
} } '
```